# Adding docstring outside function declaration

Tags: doc-strings

I have an emacs function with a long docstring.  Could I make the docstring separate from the function, adding it before or after the function declaration?

And is it possible to append to a docstring after the function has been defined and a short docstring had been inserted?

Have been introspecting the possibility of `help-split-fundoc`.  How does this work?

Answer (score 2):

```lisp
(defun hello-world ()
  (message "Hello World!"))

(put 'hello-world 'function-documentation
     "Aliqua eu excepteur incididunt quis.
Ut laborum aliqua ex amet, minim.")

(put 'hello-world 'function-documentation
     (concat
      (get 'hello-world 'function-documentation)
      "

Sed in consequat do ullamco laborum pariatur consectetur
voluptate occaecat sunt consequat aute sit in ipsum velit nisi
anim consequat.  Consequat aliqua ea cupidatat commodo magna
nulla nostrud.  Nostrud sed ea non esse duis aute irure.  Est
laboris mollit ex sit adipiscing amet, sed pariatur sunt
reprehenderit non.  In commodo est veniam, non aliqua sunt
pariatur in est consectetur cillum dolore magna aliqua commodo
ullamco."))
```

Comment: I am having a problem with `(get 'hello-world 'function-documentation)`, which does not seem to get me the documentation form the function definition.

Comment: Unfortunately, while this pattern may work suffciently well for our own functions, it breaks down for those built into emacs; sequences like `C-h f` keep showing the old documentation. I think that's because the `documentation` function looks into the canned file `etc/DOC` first and this cannot be overriden. I haven't checked the C code for `documentation`, though, so I may be wrong.